# Opencart database user issue

Tags: mysql, database, hosting, opencart, cpanel

I have a problem installing Opencart. When I get to the point where i need to type in the name and the user for database, I get an error: "Access denied for user 'slo114_agp'@'(the ip of my domain)' (using password: YES)". I am 100% sure that i am using the right password for the database user, i have also given all rights to the user. For hosting I am using hostgator and i just uploaded the files via Filezilla. Now i am not sure what you put in the hostname, since I only tested opencart locally using localhost, so here I just put in my domain.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know opencart, but maybe you can share some configuration file (after removing credentials of course). Also I'm not sure, if your question is about development or installation/usage. If the latter is the case, you might be wrong on stackoverflow.

Comment: I can't get it to work. It is about installation. I now tried using the ip of the phpmyadmin, but still won't work.

Comment: In this case I would suggest, that you ask your question on serverfault or superuser. For all these stackexchange sites you can use your existing stackoverflow login.

Comment: I added a new user and different password, and also used localhost. It worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: telnet ipaddress 3306  is working ?.

Answer (score 0):

have you flush hosts after creating user. I am setting an example for creating user on some host 192.168.10.193 and access it. I am setting % in host in syntax, i can set it any host from which i wants to login. this is for testing purpose, first you check it it works fine then replace the host with your required host.

```
Mysql> Create User bob@'%' Identified By 'test';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Mysql> flush hosts;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Mysql> exit
Bye
```

Now access the mysql server by the that user remotely.

```
hiteshmundra@smart:~$ mysql -ubob -ptest -h 192.168.10.193
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.6.24-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
Mysql>
```